# Can GetDocumentation for ITypeInfo return multiple help files within a single COM Type Library

Tags: com, typelib

`ITypeLib.GetDocumentation` would seem to return the helpfile path for the library. And `ITypeInfo.GetDocumentation` would seem to return the helpfile path for the Type.

Is it possible for a TypeInfo to have a helpfile that is different to the helpfile of the library, or other TypeInfos in the library? Or will the helpfile for all of the library's Types always be the helpfile of the library?

Are there any example of Microsoft Type Libraries that have multiple helpfiles defined in a single library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There isn't any way to author the IDL for the type library that way, the [[helpfile] attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366853(v=vs.85).aspx) is only valid on the `library` keyword.  Note the comment:

> All types in a library share the same Help file.

Being able to retrieve it also from ITypeInfo is just a convenience.  It is a hopelessly antiquated concept anyway, help is provided on web pages today.

Comment: Indeed, the help *feature* is provided on web pages, including a <kbd>F1</kbd> that takes you to a broken landing page , but in my experience, that feature isn't always *helpful*.